# Empty array being read from database

Tags: php

I'm trying to achieve something very simple. Read the details of holidays from the `holidays` table from today up to end of next year, and show the result as a var_dump of array of associative arrays (the point is that once it works, I want to be able to `json_encode()` it). Although the table has a row in it, my code returns an empty array `array(0){}`. Can somebody tell what's wrong?

```
<?php
//test file

//Database details
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'hrmsbb';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

//connect to database
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die("Connection error");
}

//Show holidays from tomorrow upto the end of next year
$d = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$date_begin = $d->format('Y-m-d');

$d->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')); //add difference of one year
$y = $d->format('Y'); //get resulting year
$date_end = "$y-12-31"; //construct date

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT holiday_id, name, date, value, comments FROM holidays 
         WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date ASC");

$query->bind_param("ss", $date_begin, $date_end);

$result = $query->execute();

if( $result === false ) { //query failed
    die("Failed to query database");
}

$query->bind_result($id, $name, $date, $value, $comments);

//return results as array of objects
$data = array();

while( $query->fetch() ) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'date' => $date, 
              'value' => $value, 'comments' => $comments);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Obviously your query returns nothing. This means that your query is wrong. Have you tried it directly on mysql - via console or phpmyadmin?

Comment: @u_mulder Ah, what an idiot I am! The existing dates in the table were outside this range. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering so that it can be closed. I was sloppy and didn't see that the table actually didn't have data that could match the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try query below instead of BETWEEN :

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT holiday_id, name, date, value, comments FROM holidays 
         WHERE date > ? AND date < ? ORDER BY date ASC");
```

By the way, I don't think you can use 'date' as the name of a column in table in mySql !
This is because of word 'date' is a keyword in mySql .

Comment: The query worked eventually; there just weren't any rows in the date range when I had posted. And by the way, it's possible to use `date` as a column name even though it's a keyword.